# how to use match() in node.js MySQL

Tags: match

Using [numtel:mysql](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql) for meteor which is [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) for meteor. How should a  [SQL match against](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) query look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like this should work.

```
return liveDb.select(
    `SELECT * 
       FROM articles 
         WHERE 
           MATCH (title,body)  
           AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`, [ { table: articles} ]
);
```